# Can we change JPA metamodel location

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can we change our JPA Metamodel location? At default it should be located in same package as Entity classes are. So there is an opportunity to configure this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that isn't supported currently.
You can see supported options here:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/tooling/metamodel-generator/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor.java#L49

Here you can see the generator would always take the package of the entity:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/tooling/metamodel-generator/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/ClassWriter.java#L61

If you have a strong use case, feel free to open an issue on that.